# Issue with user meta_query

Tags: meta-query, wp-user-query

I am creating a zip code radius search. I am pulling the all the zip codes within a radius depending on the search term through an API, then doing a user query to compare a custom meta field that has their zip and display those users if there is a match within the array of zip codes. I am doing this for both US/Canada. This is working except when I increase the radius and if that location happens to have a large amount of zip codes it breaks and no users are found. Especially in Canada there are literally thousands of zip code variations within just a 10km radius. For example if you look here https://www.freemaptools.com/find-canada-postcodes-inside-radius.htm and search T5T 3E9 there are over 10k zip code results.

This only seems to be related to having a very large array. Any thoughts?

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://app.zipcodebase.com/api/v1/radius?" . 
http_build_query($data));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
"Content-Type: application/json",
"apikey: ", ));

$zipresponse = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$json = json_decode($zipresponse);


$resultArray = json_decode($zipresponse, true);
$zipCodd = $resultArray['results'];


$newzipArray = array();
if ( !empty( $zipCodd ) ) {
    $i = 0;
    foreach($zipCodd as $data){
        $i++;
            $newzipArray[$i] = str_replace(' ', '', $data['code']);
    }
}

$user_search_args = array (
  'number'          => 50, // How many per users
  'role'            => 'subscriber',
  's'               => '*' . esc_attr( $search_term ) . '*',
  'meta_query'      => array(
     'relation'    => 'OR',
          array(
              'key'     => array('mepr-address-zip', 'mepr_second_location_zip_2','mepr_third_location_zip_3'),
              'value'   => $newzipArray,
              'compare' => 'IN'
          ),

      )
  );

$user_search_query = new WP_User_Query( $user_search_args );
```

Comment: That's because Canadian postal codes are not zip codes in any way.

Comment: @vancoder right, but that has nothing to do with it. The API pulls in all zip/postal codes within a specified radius depending on the zip/postal code searched for. This is working fine, I am pulling in the data. The problem is when I query WordPress users that have a custom meta field for their zip/postal code and compare it to the API data and display those users that have a match within the array. The users display fine depending on the size of the array. If its too large of a radius and it pulls in a ton of data no users show.

Comment: are you sure it's `WP_User_Query` that's failing? If the result from your API is too large then you shouldn't query for all the users at once, and you'll likely run into memory issues after the query has completed eitherway.

Comment: Also you've leaked your API key, you should invalidate it and request a new one

Comment: @TravisKline as this isn't a discussion forum, can you state your question in unambiguous terms? Are you looking for a way to make it accept arbitrary sizes arrays? Are you asking if that's possible? Or are you asking for a diagnosis/explanation of what's happening? You need a specific question so that you can know wether to mark an answer as accepted or not

Comment: @TomJNowell I'm looking for a diagnosis/explanation of what my be happening

Comment: what does the PHP error log say?

Comment: @TomJNowell Aha, error logs shows "KILLED QUERY", apparently a WpEngine thing. Adding define( 'WPE_GOVERNOR', false ); to the wp-config.php file fixes it. Now to see if I can find a way to speed it up. US zip codes are mostly fine, but CA just has way too many variations of postal codes within even a small radius, so I end up with many thousands of values stored in an array.

Comment: Maybe change your radius depending on country? A Canadian postal code on average covers only 20 addresses, so you're gonna get a lot more results than you would for ZIP codes.

Comment: Can you do the geospatial search in the database instead? As well as storing the postcodes store the latitude and longitude of each postcode, and then to do the search convert your input postcode to latitude and longitude then you can search your database for close matches. If you want to use [MySQL's spatial geometry data type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/spatial-types.html) you'll probably have to store these in a separate table though.